# Restangular POST data not being read by Django

Tags: angularjs, rest, post, restangular

I've done a lot of searching and nothing seems to fully address this. I've created a REST API that has a resource to send a message. The path is `/api/v1/conversation/{type}/{id}/message`. Placing a POST call to that URI will create a message for the given conversation.

Everything works great if I just use `$.post('/api/v1/conversation/sample/sample/message', {message: "All your base are belong to us"});`

However, I'd like to use Restangular, and for some reason, it is sending the POST data in a way that I have to work with request.body instead of request.POST.get('message'). This is terribly inconvenient if I have to do this with every single server side API.

Here's my Restangular code:

```
conversation = Restangular.one('conversation', scope.type).one(scope.type_id);
conversation.post('message', {message: "All your base..."})
```

To clarify, it is POSTing to the correct URI, it just is sending the post data as a payload instead of as form data. How can I configure it to send the post as form data?

Edit:
As a side note, I was able to mitigate this issue by creating a utility function:

```
def api_fetch_post(request):
    post = request.POST
    if not post:
        try:
            post = json.loads(request.body.decode(encoding='UTF-8'))
        except:
            pass
    return post
```

This way I can accept either type of POST data. Regardless, is there a way to send form data with Restangular?

Comment: How did you solve this by Restangular. Because the below solution is now working.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('message', $scope.message);
// Or use the form element and have formData = new FormData(formElement).

Restangular.one('conversation', $scope.type).one($scope.type_id)
       .withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity})
       .post(formData, null, {'Content-Type': undefined})
       .then(function(response){
           // Do something with response.                    
});
```

Comment: I use formdata with post and it appends object object to url that gives me 404. So i tried it with customPOST but turns out with same django can't parse request since it sends some weird webkit content disposition etc. Grrr.